# How to have a vector of byvalue and use a vector of pointers in conjunction?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, vector, stack

I have some vectors of class A objects:

```
 std::vector<A> *V1;
 std::vector<A> *V2;
```

etc

there is a function with a vector of pointers of A:

```
 std::vector<A *> *arranged;
```

what I need to do is put the vectors from V1, V2 etc inside arranged without destroying them in the end, so I thought that a vector of pointers to those objects... is this possible?
if yes, can you give me an example of a iteration with variable V1 and add pointers of those objects into arranged?

imagine that you, temporarly, need to sort 3 vectors of objects into one vector but you don't want to mess up the memory of the 3 vectors.

ty,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own comparator. In this case, the comparator would work on `A*`. A simple example using `int` type:

```
void fun(vector<int*>* vec)
{
  /////////
}

bool comp(int* lhs, int* rhs)
{
    return *lhs < *rhs;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> first, second;
    vector<int*> vec;

    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < first.size(); ++i)
        vec.push_back(&first[i]);
    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < second.size(); ++i)
        vec.push_back(&second[i]);

    // write your own comparator! provided above: comp
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);

    fun(&vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, so when I add the pointer to the item in the vector it wouldn't be copying but just pointing? 
My problem in understanding that is that the vector has stack stuff and not heap, so how can a external function point to it? or am I just messing up the conceptions? when you push_back something inside the vector<A> does it create it again but on the heap?

Comment: When pushing stuff in `vec' when are pushing the addresses of the variables in `first` and `second`. When sorting `vec', the values will be compared but the pointers them selves will be swapped in `vec'.

Comment: Thanks, I still have some questions regarding hean and stack but will study on google. Marked your answer and gave u a point, thanks!

Comment: `std::vector` creates a dynamic array in the heap. When you push something in it, it copies that object, and add it to its internal array. The vector object it self will be on the stack, that means the size, capacity and the pointer to the internal array. The internal array it self will be in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you've several vectors containing some object type (A), and you want to create a new vector containing the composition of all members of the other vectors w/o actually copying the objects around, or otherwise disturbing their owning-vectors in any way?

First: does the new composite vector's life definitely exist such that none of its source-vectors will change?  That is: you cannot just have raw pointers into the source-vectors from your composite vector if those pointers will be invalidated within the lifetime of your composite.

If the answer to that is anything other than "definitely, pointers will remain valid" then you need to consider using shared pointers, or something similar, such that altering the source-vectors will not leave your composite vector in an invalid state (i.e. not leave it pointing to random memory).

Assuming that the source-vectors will remain unchanged in terms of their own contents for the life span of your composite, then the simple answer is "Yes"

```
vector<A> source1;
vector<A> source2;
vector<A> source3;

vector<const A*> composite; // this is a sorted vector of the above vectors' contents (by pointer)
```

For the composite vector, you would need to put the contents (by copy) of source1-3 into it, and then sort it (or you could use a sorted container, and sort as you insert the elements).  You'll need to define your own sorting operator, one that dereferences the pointers and applies whatever sort-algorithm on the target objects themselves.

Does that help you?

Comment: it helped, but the vector won't stay alive in the end of the scope, it is a pointer as I described, but just because it will be used by some other function and in the end of the main function, I will delete it

Comment: Really understanding what pointers are all about, object-lifetime, and so-on, is critical to successful C++ programming.  Having a container of pointers requires that the things they point to remain valid for the whole time that they're pointed at!  So source1-3 cannot be destroyed (go out of scope), nor can their contents change (you can't insert things, or reorder them) or else the pointers in composite will point at random information (instead of at the objects you wanted them to).
I highly recommend Scott Myers Effective C++ series if you've not yet read it. ;)